# Is the geometrical interpretation of scalar Ricci curvature in Riemannian and pseudo-Riemannian manifold the same?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I ponder about interpretation of scalar curvature in [Schwarzschild interior solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric). It reads:
\begin{equation}\label{scalarcurvature}
-S=\varepsilon-3p \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where the dimensionless scalar curvature is defined as $S\equiv R_{l}^{l}\cdot R^{2}$,  energy density $\varepsilon\equiv {\varepsilon}~{\kappa}~c^2R^2$ and pressure $p\equiv {p}~{\kappa}~R^2$, with $\kappa$ Einstein's gravitational constant $8\pi G/c^4$ and $R$ radius of the sphere (for details see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/679431/281096). The minus sign on the left side of equation \eqref{scalarcurvature} is due to metric signature definition (+,-,-,-). For interior Schwarzschild solution it applies
\begin{equation} 
\label{energyandpressure}
\varepsilon=3\alpha,~~~p=3\alpha~\frac{\sqrt{1-\alpha u}-\sqrt{1-\alpha}}{3\sqrt{1-\alpha}-\sqrt{1-\alpha u}}.~~~~~~~~~u\equiv r^{2}/R^{2}.\tag{2}
\end{equation}

It means that scalar curvature can have both signs. Especially, at the origin ($u=0$), the equation \eqref{scalarcurvature} results in
\begin{equation}\label{origincurvature}
-S_{0}=6\alpha~\frac{3\sqrt{1-\alpha}-2}{3\sqrt{1-\alpha}-1}. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Due to equation \eqref{origincurvature} the central scalar curvature ($-S_{0}$) is positive for $\alpha<5/9$, zero for $\alpha=5/9$, and negative for $\alpha>5/9$. The radial geodesics are converging in all cases. However, converging geodesics are normally interpreted as a feature of a positive scalar curvature. How is to understand the zero and the negative scalar curvature there?
I have posted this question on physics but nobody seems to know the answer. Maybe it is something for mathematicians.

Comment: It looks like the question is addressed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506395).

Comment: Thanks, that paper seems indeed relevant to my questions. I have to study it carefully.